# Filtering table rows upon Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to filter the rows of a table to display the results of entered text in the search bar. The code below does the job but for some reason filters the column headings as well.

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    var rows = $(".Info").find("tr").hide();
    if(this.value ==""){
        rows.show();
        return;
    }
    rows.hide();
    rows.filter(function(i,v){
        var t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
            if (t.is(":Contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).show();
});
```

HTML

```
<input type = "search" name = "search" id = "search">
<table style ="width:95%" class = "Info">
    <tr>
        <th>Select </th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The user adds rows which is why i haven't written any HTML for it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/szjhngwm/

It looks like you need to filter using `tbody`

```
<table style ="width:95%" class = "Info">
<thead>    
<tr>
        <th>Select </th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
<thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

var rows = $(".Info tbody tr").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use jQuery's :gt() selector.

The only thing that would change is this line:

```
var rows = $(".Info").find("tr:gt(0)").hide();
```

Notice the addition of `:gt(0)` to your `tr`.